# How to prevent Coldfusion adding decimals to digit-only varchars?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, decimal, varchar, number-formatting

I'm using `Coldfusion8`.

I'm receiving an Ajax request with an item number (random 35 charchater string), which I need to write/retrieve to the database.

Problem is, when I'm passing only digits like:

```
 23456
```

Coldfusion outputs receiving:

```
 23456.0
```

If the string contains any letters like `A12345` it works correctly.

Some code (although this does not show what's not working:

Javascript:

```
var btn = $(this).find('input'),
    putOnRack = btn.jqmData('index'),
    form = "",
    service = "../services/handler.cfc",
    method = "process",
    returnformat = "JSON",
    targetUrl = "",
    formdata = "form_submitted=store_selection&artikelnummer="+putOnRack+"&method="+method+"&returnformat="+returnformat;

    // pass to AJAX
    ajaxFormSubmit( form, service, formdata, targetUrl, successHandler, "no", "", returnformat, "" );

var ajaxFormSubmit = 
    function ( form, service, formdata, targetUrl, successHandler, dataHandler, errorHandler, returnformat, type ){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: type == "" ? "get" : type,
        url: service,
        data: formdata,    
        dataType: returnformat,
        success: function( objResponse ){}, 
        error: function (jqXHR, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
```

In Coldfusion I'm passing this through `process`, which validates and builds the form server side, then I pass to my database handler which gets a

```
 `LOCAL.form`
```

object containing all the passed info, so my item number will be in `LOCAL.form.artikelnummer`

If I output this:

```
 cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#LOCAL.form.artikelnummer#">
```

digit only strings are treated to `.0`

**Question**
How can I make sure I end up with varchar and not numbers, when passing a parameter via AJAX to Coldfusion?

Comment: Some code (although this does not show what's not working:  then why show it?

Comment: Because if had posted no code at all, you would have written "show some code" ;-) Actually once the data "arrives" from AJAX in CF, the error ".0" is there, so I'm not really sure what to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [NumberFormat(](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/functions_m-r_08.html)). Example:

```
NumberFormat('123.0', '99999')// returns '123'
```

The second parameter is a mask that determines how your number will be displayed.

Comment: If the string can contain letters, which I inferred from the op, you'll want to run isNumeric() first.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<cfqueryparam ...>` within your `cfquery` block and specify `CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER"`. This will also prevent SQL injection attacks (p.s. you should *never* pass raw data from the end user into your database).

Recommended reading:

1. [cfqueryparam (Coldfusion 8)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/Tags_p-q_18.html)
2. [Secure your ColdFusion application against SQL injection attacks](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/sql_injection.html)

Comment: Hm. But what if I'm not doing a query? I'm sending an AJAX call with `&foo=bar`, `bar` will be mapped to `LOCAL.form.artikelnummer` and then when I output `123` to become `123.0` while `123A` stays `123A`. When I'm using this value in a query, I'm cfquery-param-ing of course. But what can I do before, when it's still a value being passed?

Comment: and good point. I will try again tonight. Problem will be even if I declare `cfqueryparam` as varchar the faulty `.0` will be taken as 2 characters, while there shouldn't be any.

Comment: I've added another answer that better addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the INT function in CF.

```
int(123.456) <!--- returns 123 --->
```

INT is like floor (round down) in other languages

See [INT()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f89.html)

You'll need to check your result to make sure if it is a number before trying to use either int or numberFormat or you'll get a `The value cannot be converted to a number` error.

```
<cfif isNumeric(yourValue)>
  <cfset yourValue = int(yourValue)>
</cfif>
```